# Ember Data + JSONAPI - Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am attempting to submit invalid data via a `POST` request to a JSONAPI-based API with Ember Data 2.10.

The API responds correctly with a `422` code and this payload in the response (note that these are [error objects](http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects), not a "normal" JSONAPI payload response):

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "title": "Title can't be blank",
    "id": "title",
    "code": "100",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/attributes/title"
    },
    "status": "422"
  }, {
    "title": "Layout can't be blank",
    "id": "layout",
    "code": "100",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/relationships/layout"
    },
    "status": "422"
  }, {
    "title": "Page type can't be blank",
    "id": "page-type",
    "code": "100",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/attributes/page-type"
    },
    "status": "422"
  }]
}
```

The errors seem to be loading mostly OK into the model, but I get this error in the console:

```
ember.debug.js:19160 Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid
  at ErrorClass.EmberError (ember.debug.js:19083)
  at ErrorClass.AdapterError (errors.js:23)
  at ErrorClass (errors.js:49)
  at Class.handleResponse (rest.js:821)
  at Class.handleResponse (data-adapter-mixin.js:100)
  at Class.superWrapper [as handleResponse] (ember.debug.js:24805)
  at ajaxError (rest.js:1342)
  at Class.hash.error (rest.js:916)
  at fire (jquery.js:3305)
  at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3435)
```

What is causing this error? Is there something wrong in the JSON payload being returned by the server? One thing that changed recently was the introduction of a pointer to `/data/relationships/layout`; is Ember Data choking on that?

I may also note that submitting similar bad data via a `PATCH` request does not trigger this error in the console.

The main problem is that this is causing an acceptance test to fail, and I can't seem to find a way around it. It would be nice to be able to test this behavior in the application, but I'll just need to leave it commented out for now.

I've also tried this on Ember Data 2.7 before updating to 2.10 to see if that would fix it. Getting the same error with both versions.

Comment: Your json doesn't seem to be in [JSON API 1.0](http://jsonapi.org/) format

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe What specifically causes it to be out of compliance with JSON API 1.0?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be in the correct format. You'd have to make your rails send something similar to  `"data": [{ "type": "error", "id": "title", "attributes": { "title": "Title can't be blank", "code": "100" }, {"type": "error" ... ` and so forth.. noticed the structure difference?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe The issue that I'm having is with error objects though, which are a different animal. http://jsonapi.org/examples/#error-objects

Comment: I was under the impression that for ember data all responses should have that format (even 4xx responses). I may be mistaken tho. my bad.

Comment: Thank you for responding though. Crickets from everyone else.

Comment: Try http://discuss.emberjs.com ?

Comment: From json api spec: "only uniqueness constraint on error objects is the id field". In your errors response, it seems you've mixed up the `id` field with what is normally the `type` field in a non-error response. Also from the spec on error objects: "id: a unique identifier for this particular occurrence of the problem." Not sure if that's the source of your error with your errors (yo dog style), but try removing it and see what changes. If you have multiple errors with the same ID, would probably mess things up.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the adapter correctly reject an invalid POST? Are you sure it's not just telling you it's doing it's job correctly? What do you get in a non-dev environment?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys I'm starting to think that maybe this is normal behavior for Ember. The main problem now is that it's causing an acceptance test to fail, and I can't seem to find a way around it. It would be nice to be able to test this behavior in the application, but I'll just need to leave it commented out for now.

Answer (score -1):

since your app uses the default adapter, make sure `JSON:API` conventions are followed for building the response

Handful of guide is provided over [here](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter)

Comment: Your answer is not helpful. I posted the payload in my question. What is wrong with it specifically?

Comment: Your error payload is correct. I think you’re on the right path. This is the normal behaviour of ember. Ember Data is letting you know that the model didn’t successfully save because the server responded with a 422